# programmatically stop a windows service using ruby

Tags: ruby, windows-services

Is there a way to stop a windows service (possibly on a remote machine) using ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The %x command, and Windows command line utilities like "AT" and "NET STOP".

e.g.

```
@result = %x[AT \\computername 00:00 "NET STOP service"]
```

00:00 being the current time plus a reasonable buffer to account for the clocks being out of sync. Also, the AT command requires elevation on Vista/Server 2008/Windows 7.

Comment: I've used "net" many times, although I've switched to "sc" which has more capability than "net" (and looks more logical since most services have nothing to do with "net"working.) :)
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx